# Getting user profile data in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, asp.net-profiles

I am fairly new to Silverlight and RIA services, and I am trying to build a small project to understand it.  So basically I created a Business Application, and I have the normal Login screen where I can add a user.  That is fine and I can add a user and get him into the aspnet_Users table.  Now I have created some extra fields, like Mob No, Tel No, DOB, Locality etc, which I have put in a table I have created called the UserProfile, and my idea is to get the username that was registered, and insert it into my UserProfile table with the other relevant data.

So I created a page called Profile.xaml, I created a UserProfileDomainService.cs where I have just one query, to get the user profile data from the table, and then created a Details DataGrid on my page, and the QueryName in my case is GetUserProfilesQuery().  Now what i wish to do is, get the user logged in, get his username, and check in my table to see if there is already data in the table.  If there is populate the fields on the DataGrid with data, so that the user can modify this data, and if not, allow the user to insert data into the table.

So I have created a UserProfileViewModel class, and I want to create the query to get the data relevant to this user.  However I got stuck on how to do all this, and how to get the user logged in.

Can anybody give me some advice or point me to some tutorials on how I can achieve this?

Thanks a lot and your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your domain service query you can use ServiceContext.User.Identity.Name to get the information specific to that user to include in your db query. I do something similar in our project.

We use entity framework so the LINQ to Entities query looks like:

```
   return this.ObjectContext.UserSnapins
        .Include("Snapin.EvolutionModule")
        .Where(si => si.User.UserName == ServiceContext.User.Identity.Name)
        .OrderBy(si => si.PageOrder);
```